# Regex matching in C

Tags: c, regex, string

I'm writing a parser that analyze the content passed in parameter and compare to a regex.
This parser should return boolean if found a structure of variable :

> int a;
>
> double abc;
>
> char test;

Those variables should match but not...

Here is my code, I thought my regex is true..

```
#include "includes.h"

int check_match_var(char *str)
{
  int err;
  int match;
  regex_t preg;
  char err_buf[BUFSIZ];
  const char *regex = "/^(int|char|float|double) [a-zA-Z0-9]{1,};/";

  err = regcomp(&preg, regex, 0);
  printf("Err : %d\n", err);
  if (err == 0)
    {
      match = regexec(&preg, str, 0, NULL, 0);
      regfree(&preg);
      if (match == 0)
    printf("Match !\n");
      else
    printf("No match !\n");
    }
  else
    {
      regerror(err, &preg, err_buf, BUFSIZ);
      printf("regcomp: %s\n", err_buf);
      return (1);
    }
  return (0);
}

int marvin(char **av)
{
  check_match_var(av[1]);
  return (0);
}

int main(int ac, char **av)
{
  if (ac == 2)
    {
      marvin(av);
    }
  else
    printf("\n");
  return (0);
}
```

Anyway it return 1 (no match), I want it return 0 (match)..

Includes file :

```
#ifndef INCLUDES_H_

#define INCLUDES_H_
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <regex.h> 
#endif
```

Thanks for help

Comment: I don't think POSIX regexes want the leading/trailing `/` characters - they may be treated as part of the actual regex pattern.

Comment: I've added them after the bug, trying to see if changes something

Comment: As a basic debugging step, print out the string that is being searched, just to make sure the program got what you think it got.

Comment: The slashes are one problem, but where there's one, there are often several, and this is no exception.  Since you don't include REG_EXTENDED in the third argument to [`regcomp()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/regcomp.html), the `|` and `(` and `)` are not metacharacters.

Comment: Works with mine / @JonathanLeffler's suggestions: https://ideone.com/4JE7wF

Comment: Thanks @JonathanLeffler! Worked adding REG_NOSUB | REG_EXTENDED

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code is using the POSIX regular expression code from `<regex.h>`.  You can find the information about [`regcomp()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/regcomp.html) and `regexec()` online.

There are two problems with the code posted:

1. [Paul Roub](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1324/paul-roub) correctly [identified](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27748999/regex-matching-in-c#comment43909345_27748999) that the slashes in the regex string are not required.
2. [Jonathan Leffler](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15168/jonathan-leffler) correctly [identified](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27748999/regex-matching-in-c#comment43909424_27748999) that the regular expressions processed by `regcomp()` and `regexec()` are 'basic regular expressions' or BRE, but the notation is trying to use 'extended regular expressions' or ERE.  And the way to request ERE support is via the `REG_EXTENDED` flag as one of the flags in the third argument to `regcomp()`.

In a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27748999/regex-matching-in-c#comment43909464_27748999), [user3486006](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3486006/user3486006) confirms that both changes (and adding `REG_NOSUB` to the `regcomp()`) means that it works.  See the manual page for what `REG_NOSUB` does; the match would have worked with or without the flag, but adding the flag is sensible in this context.

<sup>*Community Wiki answer: if Paul posts an answer, accept it, please.*</sup>